# Question on Geometry, triangles and circles

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a right-angled triangle with $B = 90^\circ$ and let $BD$ be the altitude from $B$ on to $AC$. Draw $DE$  perpendicular to $AB$ and $DF$ perpendicular to $BC$. Let $P, Q, R$ and $S$ be respectively the incentres of triangles $DFC, DBF, DEB$ and $DAE$. Suppose $S, R, Q$ are collinear. Prove that $P, Q, R, D$ lie on a circle.

[image]

Comment: The location of $E$ and $F$ cannot be determined from the question. Did you intend $E$ to be on $AB$ and $F$ to be on $BC$?

Comment: @ Element118 i have edited question plz see

Comment: "Draw DE perpendicular AB and DF perpendicular BC".  This sentence is unreadable.

Comment: @fleablood plz read question now.

Comment: I would just like to add that the triangle with this property is none other than the famous $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle.

Answer (score 1):

The direct similitude $u$ taking triangle $DAB$ to $DBC$ consists of a $90^{\circ}$ rotation with centre $D$ followed by a dilation with centre $D$. We have $u(E) = F$, $u(S) = Q$, $u(R) = P$.

Since $u(R) = P$, we have $\angle RDP = 90^{\circ}$. Therefore $D$ is on the circle with diameter $RP$.

Also, $u$ takes line $SR$ to line $QP$, hence these lines are perpendicular.

By assumption, the line $SR$ coincides with line $RQ$. Therefore $\angle RQP = 90^{\circ}$. Consequently, not only $D$ but also $Q$ is on the circle with diameter $PR$.

Comment: what is similitude?

Comment: A similarity transformation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similarity_in_Euclidean_space